# Restore of database 'DatabaseName' failed. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

This is for Windows 10, running Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.1. I've tried on SQL Server 2012 & 2014, getting the same error.

I restored the DB using these steps

```
* Right Click on Databases
  >> Restore Database 
     >> Selected Device under source
        >> clicked ... 
           >> Select backup devices
              >> Add
                 >> Select .bak file
                    >> Ok
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to restore a database on SQL Server Express edition. [The maximum allowed database size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017#Cross-BoxScaleLimits) on this edition is 10 GB.

You must restore this backup on another edition of SQL Server, like Developer (free for non-production use), Standard, Enterprise or Trial.

Comment: I am using Express, should I change from that to the ones that you have mentioned?

Comment: Yes, you need to upgrade it

Comment: okay let me try and I'll get back to you ASAP. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: You are either not installing what you think, or not connecting to the server you think. Run `select @@VERSION` and check the result returned, e.g. "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4458842) - 13.0.4224.16 (X64) 
 Aug 18 2018 09:00:06 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 **Standard Edition (64-bit)** on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)"

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4494351) - 14.0.2014.14 (X64)   Apr  5 2019 09:18:51   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )

Comment: This is the version I'm running

Comment: So you are sill running Express Edition. It doesn't allow databases bigger than 10 GB. You must restore your backup on an instance running another edition. If you installed another edition on the same computer, check the name of the instance - do not connect to {something}\SQLEXPRESS, but to {something} or {something}\{somethingelse}

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Open SSMS and connect to the db.

Step 2: After connecting to the database, Object Explorer panel will appear on the left side of the SSMS window.

Step 3: In Object Explorer panel, right-click Databases, and then select Restore Database.
Select Restore Database Option

Step 4: In Restore Database dialog box, do the following:

Select one of the databases to restore.
In the left panel, click Options.

Step 5: In Options page, check the checkbox labeled, ‘close existing connections to destination database’.

Close existing database connections

OBS: In case you can't mark the "close existing connections to destination database" checkbox ( sometimes this option will appear in a grey color, you can just go to the "restore options" which will appear right in the top of the box, and mark the checkbox "Overwrite the existing database(WITH REPLACE)". and then a message will pop up in your screen telling you the database was successful restored. - by Levy Pinheiro.

Once the SQL Server connections are closed, proceed with the restore operation.